# Finding UDDI key/value on local?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

How i can find UDDI key/value  of web service currently running in my local machine. 
The web service URL is http://localhost:8080/ts?wsdl

Here is way i am publishing the WS in main program

```
Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
```

Some services are also published thru spring

Comment: I am not an expert in SOAP but i find this related http://soa.sys-con.com/node/39868